# Prove that $\{Y:Y \subseteq X\}$ is a set.

Tags: real-analysis, functions, elementary-set-theory, solution-verification, inverse-function

I am a beginner and self-learning Real Analysis. Problem 3.4.6 from Tao's `Analysis-I` poses the following question. I'd like to someone to verify my proof, and help me write a technically correct proof.

> Let $X$ be a set. Then the set $\{Y : Y \text{ is a subset of } X\}$ is a set.

(Hint given with the question: start with the set $\{0, 1\}^X$ and apply the replacement axiom, replacing each function $f$ with the object $f^{-1}(\{1\})$.)

***My Attempt.***

Using the Power set Axiom, if $X$ and $Y$ are sets, then $Y^X$ consists of all functions for
$X \to Y$

I assume for simplicity that set $X$ has two elements $\{x_1,x_2\}$.

By definition of the power set axiom, the set $Y^X$ consists of 4 functions as follows :

$f_1 \text{ maps } x_1\to 0 \text{ and } x_2 \to 0$
$f_2 \text{ maps } x_1\to 0 \text{ and } x_2 \to 1$
$f_3 \text{ maps } x_1\to 1 \text{ and } x_2 \to 0$
$f_4 \text{ maps } x_1\to 1 \text{ and } x_2 \to 1$

I want to apply the replacement axiom, replacing each function $f_i$ with the object $f_i^{-1}(\{1\})$.

$\{ f_1^{-1}(\{1\}),f_2^{-1}(\{1\}),f_3^{-1}(\{1\}),f_4^{-1}(\{1\})\}$
$\implies$ $\{ \emptyset,\{x_2\},\{x_1\},\{x_1,x_2\} \} $  which consists of all subsets of $X$.

*** My Question***

> 1. I have simply replaced the functions$(f_1,f_2,f_3,f_4)$ with the object $f^{-1}(\{1\})$. In order to use the replacement axiom, I must show that for each $x$, the statement $P(x,y)$ is true for atmost one $y$. What should be the proposition $P(x,y)$?

> 2. $\{x_1,x_2\}$ consists of all the elements of $X$, but from the definition of a function we know that bijective functions are invertible, but in the last function both  $\{x_1,x_2\}$ map to $1$, in that case, I don't think I can write
>    $f_4^{-1}(\{1\})$=$\{x_1,x_2\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your last question first, if $f\in Y^X$, the notation $f^{-1}$ has two possible meanings. If $f$ is a bijection, it can denote the inverse function to $f$. In all cases, however, it can be applied to subsets of $Y$: for any $A\subseteq Y$,

$$f^{-1}[A]=\{x\in X:f(x)\in A\}\,.$$

In particular, $f_4^{-1}[\{1\}]$ **is** $\{x_1,x_2\}$ in your example. (See Tao’s **Definition** $\mathbf{3.4.4}$.)

It should be intuitively clear that

$$\{Y:Y\subseteq X\}=\left\{f^{-1}[\{1\}]:f\in\{0,1\}^X\right\}\,,\tag{1}$$

so we have two tasks: we must show that $(1)$ is actually true, and we must show that the object on the righthand side of $(1)$ is a set.

It’s for the second task that we want replacement. For each $f\in\{0,1\}^X$ let $P(f,y)$ be the statement

$$y=\{x\in X:f(x)=1\}\,.$$

It is straightforward to prove that for each $f$ in $X^{\{0,1\}}$ there is a unique $y$ such that $P(f,y)$ is true, and that $y$ is evidently $f^{-1}[\{1\}]$, so we can apply replacement to conclude that

$$\left\{f^{-1}[\{1\}]:f\in\{0,1\}^X\right\}$$

is a set.

I’ll leave it to you to prove $(1)$.

Comment: *sigh* A downvote made without explanation is *at best* useless, both to the author of the answer and to later readers, and at worst it is vandalism.

Comment: Hi Brian. I posted an answer below showing that $ \{Y:Y \subseteq X\} = \{f^{-1}(\{1\}): f \in \{0, 1\}^X \} $. Could you please review the proof and verify it's correct or not? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are working within the ZF set theory, [this is an axiom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_power_set).

Comment: But not in Tao’s version of $\mathsf{ZF}$. In his version the power set axiom is stated as follows: Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets. Then there exists a set, denoted by $Y^X$, which consists of all the functions from $X$ to $Y$, thus $$f\in Y^X\iff(f\text{ is a function with domain }X\text{ and range }Y)\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

To prove: $\{Y : Y\subseteq X\} = \{ f^{-1} [\{1\}] : f \in \{0,1\}^X\}$ is true .

Proof :

1. **Definition of Inverse Images** : If U is a subset of Y, we  define the set
   $f^{-1}(U):= \{x \in X :f(x) \in U\}.$ ,
   where we call $f^{-1}(U)$ the inverse image of $U$.
2. Mapping our statement, to the definition of Inverse images,we understand,
   If $U = \{1\}^X$, is a subset to the larger set $f \in \{0,1\}^X$ thus, $U\subseteq f$.
   The statement $f^{-1}[\{1\}]$ corresponds to all the subsets of $X$ for which $U$ is true.
   Hence, the statement $\{ f^{-1} [\{1\}] : f \in \{0,1\}^X\}$ is well-defined as per the definition of inverse images.
3. To prove the equivalence, we first prove $\{Y : Y\subseteq X\}\subseteq  \{ f^{-1} [\{1\}] : f \in \{0,1\}^X\}$
   Let $\{x\} \in Y \implies \{x\} \subseteq X \implies \{1\}^{\{x\}} \subseteq \{0,1\}^X \implies U \subseteq Y \implies f^{-1}(U) \subseteq f^{-1}(Y)$.
   Thus proving, $\{Y : Y\subseteq X\} \subseteq \{ f^{-1} [\{1\}] : f \in \{0,1\}^X\}$
4. To prove the other subset equivalent.
   Let $\{x\} \subseteq f^{-1}(U) \implies \{x\} \in Y$ as stated $\{Y \subseteq X\} \implies \{x\} \in \{Y : Y \subset X \}$
   Thus proving,  $\{ f^{-1} [\{1\}] : f \in \{0,1\}^X\}  \subseteq \{Y : Y\subseteq X\}$

Therefore, proving the equality  $\{Y : Y\subseteq X\} = \{ f^{-1} [\{1\}] : f \in \{0,1\}^X\}$

Answer (score 0):

> I'm posting my own answer to show that
>
> $$ \{Y:Y \subseteq X\} = \{f^{-1}(\{1\}): f \in \{0, 1\}^X \} $$

**Case 1:** We first show $ \{Y:Y \subseteq X\} \subseteq \{f^{-1}(\{1\}): f \in \{0, 1\}^X \}$.

Let $W \in \{Y:Y \subseteq X\}$; this implies that $W \subseteq X$. We want to show $$W \in \{f^{-1}(\{1\}): f \in \{0, 1\}^X \}$$ which requires us to show that there exists a function $f \in \{0, 1\}^X$ such that
$W = f^{-1}(\{1\})$, where $f^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{x \in X : f(x) \in \{1\}\}$.

Let's define a function $f: X \rightarrow \{0, 1\}$ by

$$
f(x) = 
\begin{cases}
1, & \text{if }\  x=w \\
0, & \text{if }\  x \neq w
\end{cases}
$$

**Subcase 1(i):** We show $W \subseteq f^{-1}(\{1\})$.

Since $W \subseteq X$, we have that for any $w \in W$, that $w \in X$. This implies $w = x$ for some $x \in X$. Thus, $f(w) = 1$ by our definition of $f$. Since $w$ is arbitrary, this shows for any $w \in W$, we have $f(w) \in \{1\}$. This implies $w \in f^{-1}(\{1\})$ and hence, $W \subseteq f^{-1}(\{1\})$.

**Subcase 1(ii):** We show $f^{-1}(\{1\}) \subseteq W$.

If $x \in f^{-1}(\{1\})$, then $f(x)=1$. But this is true only when $x=w$ by our definition of $f$, and so, $x \in W$. Hence, $f^{-1}(\{1\}) \subseteq W$.

Proving the above two subcases shows $W = f^{-1}(\{1\})$, and thus shows $W \in \{f^{-1}(\{1\}): f \in \{0, 1\}^X \}$. Hence, $ \{Y:Y \subseteq X\} \subseteq \{f^{-1}(\{1\}): f \in \{0, 1\}^X \}$.

**Case 2:** We now show $ \{f^{-1}(\{1\}): f \in \{0, 1\}^X \} \subseteq \{Y:Y \subseteq X\}  $.

Let $Z \in \{f^{-1}(\{1\}): f \in \{0, 1\}^X \}$. Then $Z = f^{-1}(\{1\})$ for some $f \in \{0, 1\}^X $. But $f^{-1}(\{1\}) = \{x \in X : f(x) \in \{1\}\}$, implying that $f^{-1}(\{1\}) \subseteq X$. Since $Z = f^{-1}(\{1\})$, it implies $Z \subseteq X$, and so, $Z \in \{Y:Y \subseteq X\}$ Hence, $ \{f^{-1}(\{1\}): f \in \{0, 1\}^X \} \subseteq \{Y:Y \subseteq X\}  $.

By showing Case 1 and Case 2 above, we have shown that $ \{Y:Y \subseteq X\} = \{f^{-1}(\{1\}): f \in \{0, 1\}^X \} $.